# Java CertificateException No subject alternative names matching IP address(trying to create user in AD)

Tags: java, active-directory, ldap

The problem is when I try to create user in Active Directory (AD) with Java I get this exception but when I want to get values from already existing user there is no problem. And I need the kind of solution which will make it work not only locally on my computer but globally(I don't want to force other people to make the same configurations).

I tried to import/export ssl certificate but there are 2 problems. The first one is it didn't work out and the second one is that even if it works out that way, this will be only a locally solution.

```
public void createUser(String username, String surname, String givenName) throws NamingException {

    //the exception is right here when I'm trying to initialize
    DirContext context = new InitialDirContext(ldapEnv);

    String distinguishedName = "cn=" + username + BASE;
    Attributes newAttributes = new BasicAttributes(true);
    Attribute objClasses = new BasicAttribute("objectclass");
    objClasses.add("top");
    objClasses.add("person");
    objClasses.add("organizationalperson");
    objClasses.add("user");
    newAttributes.put(objClasses);
    newAttributes.put(new BasicAttribute("sAMAccountName", username));
    newAttributes.put(new BasicAttribute("cn", username));
    newAttributes.put(new BasicAttribute("sn", surname));
    newAttributes.put(new BasicAttribute("givenName", givenName));
    newAttributes.put(new BasicAttribute("displayName", givenName + " " + surname));
    System.out.println("Creating: " + username);
    context.createSubcontext(distinguishedName, newAttributes);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> No subject alternative names matching IP address

The issue sounds like it's something that applies to *any* SSL connection, not just for LDAP.

An SSL certificate has a primary domain name, and "subject alternative names", which are a list of other domain names that the cert can be used for. When you initiate an SSL connection, your computer reads the cert, looks at all the domain names the cert is allowed to be used for, and checks if any of them match **the domain name you used to initiate the connection**. This is to ensure that you are connecting to the correct server, because that is part of the job of secure communication (not *just* encrypting).

And there is the problem: If you used the IP address, like this:

```
ldapEnv.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "ldaps://192.168.1.1:636");
```

then the SSL handshake is guaranteed to fail, since SSL certs are not issued to IP addresses. You must use one of the domain names listed in the SSL certificate:

```
ldapEnv.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "ldaps://example.com:636");
```

Comment: Just one point to add/highlight in your answer: "*....since SSL certs are not issued to IP addresses....*" -> SSL certificates can have SAN containing the IP-Addresses as well!

Comment: I've done that , but still the same. Can you send me an example of how to configure ssl handshake because I'm not 100% sure that I'm doing it right and maybe the issue is there.

Comment: You don't handle the SSL handshake yourself. That's done for you. When you change it to use a domain name you know is in the cert, does the error message change? It's also possible that the issuer of the cert is not trusted.

Comment: @Am_I_Helpful Interesting! I didn't know that.